# Ubuntu 13.04 doesn't show confirmation dialog for shutdown

Tags: shutdown, 13.04

After I updated to 13.04, Ubuntu immediately shuts down without confirmation when I press the power button. Also, it doesn't ask for confirmation if I select an otion from the top-right gear menu.
I tried setting the flag org.gnome.gnome-session.logout-prompt to true in dconf-editor and I set the power button action to "Interactive" in Tweak Tool.

Comment: Temporarily you can use `sudo shutdown -r` to "restart" given that there's no direct menu option for it.

Comment: There is a menu option for it, but no confirmation dialog and the power button always shuts down my machine, regardless of the actual setting.

Comment: This might be a bug. Hard to know anything or even do background research without knowing more about the laptop. (Manu? Product code? System specs?)

Comment: It can't be the hardware, because it worked until I upgraded and also the shutdown procedure should only start after a confirmation, which has nothing to do with hardware.

Comment: You misunderstood, I'm not saying it's your hardware, I'm saying it might be a software problem specifically related to your hardware.

Comment: I know, but this would be really strange. Also there are no relevant log entries for this. It's a pretty generic notebook from ChiliGreen, on which everything else works fine.
Does anyone know where it *should* be turned off and on?

Comment: Have you tried reseting unity? Try these instructions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/286349#286349 tweak tool breaks things sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution!
Apparently the setting of `/org/gnome/gnome-session/logout-prompt` is ignored in newer Ubuntu versions, the right key was `/apps/indicator-session/suppress-logout-restart-shutdown`.
So to fix this, do **`dconf write /apps/indicator-session/suppress-logout-restart-shutdown false`** in terminal. It should take effect immediately without restart.
It seems that sometimes this value is set to „true“ by upgrade or third party applications.

Answer (score -1):

In ubuntu 13.04 i find this is working, so please open a terminal and type or better copy and paste the row below then press enter:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/gnome-session/logout-prompt false
```

Comment: Not only is this question already solved, but you suggested tampering with the exact setting that was found out to not work anymore in 13.04 _and_ if it would, your suggestion would do the _exact opposite_ of what I wanted.